# How to pass value in bootstrap v4 modal?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

As you can see below, I have a php-generated table with a **td** that contains both **edit and delete anchors**. I put the **$data['id']** inside the **data-id** attribute of the anchor and I pass it to the modal via jquery. However, the ID of the article is not being displayed on the modal. Can someone tell what is wrong with my codes? Is it the php, the html, or the jquery? Thanks!

```
<?php
     require "../connection.php";
     $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `articles`");
     while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<th scope="row">'.$data['id'].'</th>';
         echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="#myModal" data-id="'.$data['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></div></td>';
         echo '</tr>';
     }
?>
```

**PHP-GENERATED TABLE**

```
<!-- Modal-->
<div id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade text-left">
     <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Edit Article</h5>
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
               </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Please save your changes after editing the article.</p>
          <form id="myForm">
               <div class="form-group">
               <label>ID</label>
               <input type="text" value="" name="articleId" id="articleId" class="form-control">
          </form>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**HTML MODAL**

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // get information to update quickly to modal view as loading begins
  var opener=e.relatedTarget;//this holds the element who called the modal

   //we get details from attributes
  var myArticleId=$(opener).attr('data-id');

//set what we got to our form
  $('#myForm').find('[name="articleId"]').val(myArticleId);

});
```

**JQUERY**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Summary</th>
  <th>Content</th>
  <th><div align="center">Date Published</div></th>
  <th><div align="center">Date Last Edited</div></th>
  <th><div align="center">Action</div></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
   <td><div align="center"><a href="#articleEditModal" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="#articleEditModal" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="#articleEditModal" data-id="3" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>                    
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**INSPECTED PAGE - TABLE**

```
$('#articleEditModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
```

An error shows on this line above:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at cms.php:162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var opener = $(e.relatedTarget);` instead of `var opener=e.relatedTarget;`

Reference [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Hope this helps!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>
            <a href="#articleEditModal" data-article-id="2" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> 
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<!-- Modal-->
<div id="articleEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade text-left">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Edit Article</h5>
         <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <p>Please save your changes after editing the article.</p>
         <form id="myForm">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>ID</label>
               <input type="text" value="" name="articleId" id="articleId" class="form-control">
         </form>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#articleEditModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

    var article_id = button.attr('data-article-id')
    // take advantage of data attribute
    // var article_id = button.data('article-id'); 

    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Article ' + article_id)
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(article_id)
})
</script>
```

// Sample php data

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php
     require "../connection.php";
     $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `articles`");
     while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th scope="row">'.$data['id'].'</th>';
        echo '<td><div align="center"><a href="#myModal" data-id="'.$data['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></div></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
     }
?>
<!-- Modal-->
<div id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade text-left">
     <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 id="exampleModalLabel" class="modal-title">Edit Article</h5>
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
               </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Please save your changes after editing the article.</p>
          <form id="myForm">
               <div class="form-group">
               <label>ID</label>
               <input type="text" value="" name="articleId" id="articleId" class="form-control">
          </form>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
     </div>
 </div>

<script>
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // get information to update quickly to modal view as loading begins
  var opener=$(e.relatedTarget);//this holds the element who called the modal

   //we get details from attributes
  var myArticleId=$(opener).attr('data-id');

//set what we got to our form
  $('#myForm').find('[name="articleId"]').val(myArticleId);

});

</script>
```

Comment: I have tested your code on a plain html file and it seems to be working. However when I try to test it on my project, it does not work. The modal is still displaying an empty input box. Is it because of the php?

Comment: Hi Matthew Miranda, I assume the database returns the data. Edited the answer. Try this. Cross check once $data['id'] returns the article id

Comment: Sivaraj, really sorry to bother your time, but I changed my php code to yours and still got no results in the modal. I am running out of options to enable to run this modal perfectly..

Comment: Inspect the page and share the <table> code If i see the code, may be I could help you with that

Comment: Sivaraj, I have updated my post. Please refer to it.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> check jquery library exists

Comment: Sivaraj, I have just updated the css and js libraries as you mentioned but still got no luck. :( Are there still other options?

Comment: Try replace the sample data - edited (one thing you have to add table head )